# Core Data and 'double' property not working. A number is converted into a nan?

Tags: ios, core-data, double, nan

I have a bizarre problem with a 'double' property in Core Data.
I have isolated the problem in these two lines:

```
newStrategy.order = 444.0; 
NSLog(@"Order is %f", newStrategy.order);
```

The output of that NSLog is:

```
Order is nan
```

newStrategy type is 'Strategy', one of the entities I have defined in Core Data. The 'order' property is declared as

```
@property (nonatomic) double order;
```

in a Core Data generated file.

Of course, when data is saved, the 'order' is not stored as 444.0. The strange situation is that I have other Core Data entities (with associated files) that use a similar 'order' property, as a double, and they gave me no problems at all in similar operations.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is order properly defined as a double in the core data model ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have changed now to a float (everywhere, model and source files) and it seems to work. But is not a satisfactory solution, is just a hack. I think that the problem is related to too many 'order' properties in my app. I have 3 entities and all them use a double 'order' property. Could that be ?

Comment: asilva, No, property names on entities are independent. I have a `date` property on almost every entity in my apps. There is no problem with this. Andrew

Comment: Puzzling. I would check the model file, the XML code, to ensure the attribute is properly defined. Removing the attribute and recreating it may also help, if something's wrong in the model file. Besides that, dunno. Defining your own (double) order and (void) setOrder: (double) value with logs and breakpoints may help to find what's wrong.

Comment: Does your order attribute deal with money? If so, it could be more correct to use decimals...

Comment: Thanks fabrice. After trying it with a float I changed it back to a double and now it seems to be working. As you said some kind of recreation helped. Possible lesson learned: if problems with Core Data seem illogical, or behaviour seems inconsistent, recreating the model could help.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help somehow.

Comment: Please,if possible put your solution as an answer and mark it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to add the solution but need to wait a few hours, as I am new here. I will do when possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some inconsistency in the Core Data model was the cause, so recreating the attribute helps. I changed it from 'double' to 'float', in the model and in the .h files. Then, I went back to a 'double' again and now it's working.